# update and select from a database table

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert

I have two database tables, "user" which have 3 columns (id,[auto increment] username and pinch)
The other table is "pins" which has only one column (scratches)
MY TABLES

```
USER
Id       username      Pinc


1         Josh             

2         Angela         

3          Chika 


PINS
scratches


123456


234515

124564
```

I want a situation when a user submit his password via a form, it will check in the pins table to know whether such data exist, if it does, it will update the pinc column of my user table with the form post and log in with it. If it doesn't exist in the pins table it will give an error "sorry the pin does not exist."
MY CODE

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM    pins WHERE scratches = '" .' $user_password '. "';";
$query = $this->db_connection->query($sql);
if ($query->num_rows== 0){
   $this->errors[] = "Sorry, that PIN does not exist.";
} elseif ($query->num_rows== 1) {  
    $sql = "UPDATE user ".
      "SET pinc = $user_password ".
      "WHERE user_name = $user_name" ;
    $query_new_user_insert = $this->db_connection->query($sql);

    $sql = "SELECT  user_name, pinc 
              FROM user
              WHERE user_name = '" . $user_name . "' ;";
    $result_of_login_check = $this->db_connection->query($sql);
    // if this user exists
    if ($result_of_login_check->num_rows == 1) {
        // get result row (as an object)
        $result_row = $result_of_login_check->fetch_object();
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result_row->user_name;
        $_SESSION['user_login_status'] = 1;
    } else {
       $this->errors[] = "Wrong password. Try again.";
    }
} else {
    $this->errors[] = "This user does not exist.";
}
} else {
   $this->errors[] = "Database connection problem.";
}
}
}
```

when i run the code, i get "sorry pin does not exist." Can someone tell me whats wrong with it?

Comment: change your first query to this `$sql = "SELECT * FROM    pins WHERE scratches = '".$user_password."';";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using singe quete `''`around `$userpassword` means, so You are passing as string
Change your first query like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM    pins WHERE scratches = '".$user_password."';";
```

And your second query as also wrong. as i am assuming `$username` is a string, 
You need to wrap it around single quete `''` like this

```
$sql = "UPDATE user ".
   "SET pinc = '$user_password' ".
   "WHERE user_name = '$user_name'" ;//You are missing single quete here if username is a string
```

I dont know this is also problem or not, But have extra space in your third query. for your `$username` variable after contanitation (after point `. .` ). If that does not work remove it like this

```
$sql = "SELECT  user_name, pinc 
              FROM user
              WHERE user_name = '".$user_name."' ;";
```

**

### This is your full code should look like

**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM    pins WHERE scratches = '".$user_password ."';";
$query = $this->db_connection->query($sql);
if ($query->num_rows== 0){
   $this->errors[] = "Sorry, that PIN does not exist.";
} elseif ($query->num_rows== 1) {  
    $sql = "UPDATE user SET pinc ='".$user_password."' WHERE user_name ='".$user_name."'" ;
    $query_new_user_insert = $this->db_connection->query($sql);



    $sql = "SELECT  user_name, pinc FROM user WHERE user_name = '".$user_name."' ;";


    $result_of_login_check = $this->db_connection->query($sql);
    // if this user exists
    if ($result_of_login_check->num_rows == 1) {
        // get result row (as an object)
        $result_row = $result_of_login_check->fetch_object();
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result_row->user_name;
        $_SESSION['user_login_status'] = 1;
    } else {
       $this->errors[] = "Wrong password. Try again.";
    }
} else {
    $this->errors[] = "This user does not exist.";
}
} 
}
}
```

Comment: Do I need to include if       (isset($_POST["login"]))

Comment: @Gentledozy `isset` only check some thing. its better if you do it, But you are setting your variable value na. means you need to sate like thie `$login=$_POST['login']`; you are doing that na.

Comment: It worked but didn't update the table user with the password at the pinc column

Comment: @Arid I meant 
    if (isset($_POST["update"]))
also the table didn't update but it logged in. I changed the update query as u suggested
     $sql = "UPDATE user ".
   "SET pinc = '$user_password' ".
   "WHERE user_name = '$user_name'" ;

Comment: Check this question out?
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26396649/update-and-select-from-a-database-table/26396703?
noredirect=1#comment41446369_26396703

Answer (score 1):

Strange string structure:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pins WHERE scratches = '" .' $user_password '. "';";
```

It will select all data from pins WHERE scrathes = "$user_password". It will return data not found.

Modify it like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM    pins WHERE scratches = '" . $user_password . "';";
```

Tell me how it works.

Comment: Let me check it out.     if (isset($_POST["login"]))

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 I don't know. That's all depending to people who make question. It's not about vote my brother. For me it's about helping each other with your heart and skill. Vote is only a score. If you are looking for vote, never mind I will vote your comment for you. Cheer up buddy

Comment: The same with answer. Have you tried to change this part?
`$sql = "UPDATE user SET pinc = '".$user_password."' WHERE user_name = '".$user_name."' ;` Please read more about `string` manipulation in php hope you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM    pins WHERE scratches = '" .' $user_password '. "';";
```

to

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM    pins WHERE scratches = '".$user_password."'";
```